# $\mathcal L_p([0,1],S,\lambda)$ is separable for $p\in(0,\infty)$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $\Omega=[0,1]$, $S$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra in $[0,1]$ and $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure over $S$. So I want to prove that:

> $$\mathcal L_p(\Omega,S,\lambda) \text{  is separable for  }p\in(0,\infty)$$

My attempt:

I'm lost with this one since I can't see how to give a countable dense set in $\mathcal L_p$. What I got is that:

Let $f\in\mathcal L_p$, so $f$ is measurable then, by Luzin's theorem, we can assure that:

$$
\forall\epsilon>0\;\exists E_{\epsilon}\text{  open with }\lambda(E_{\epsilon})<\epsilon\text{  s.t.  }\;\;f\big|_{\Omega\setminus E}\text{  is continuous}
$$

and then, by Weierstrass aproximation theorem, we get that:

$$
\forall \tilde\epsilon>0\;\exists p_{\tilde\epsilon}(x)\text{  s.t. }|f(x)-p_{\tilde\epsilon}(x)|<\tilde\epsilon
$$

but got stucked here trying to figure out how this connects with the idea of finding a countable dense set. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Short answer: linear combinations of indicator functions of intervals with rational endpoints. It is easier if you already know that simple functions or continuous functions are dense. Do you have these facts at your disposal?

Comment: @User8128 You'll be wanting the coefficients in those linear combinations to be rational?

Comment: @User8128 I don't know. By Weierstrass I know that polynomials are dense in the space of continuous functions. Could you give a more detailed explanation please.

Comment: @zhw. Yes of course, I forgot to put that but certainly the coefficients should be rational.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach suggested in the comments is to use functions like $$f = \sum^n_{i=1} \alpha_i \chi_{[a_i, b_i]}, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (\text{I use } \chi \text{ to denote an indicator function)}$$ where $n \in \mathbb N, \alpha_i, a_i, b_i \in \mathbb Q$. The set of all such functions is countable since it can be identified with $\mathbb N \times \mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$ and it is dense in $\mathcal L^p([0,1])$ since any continuous function on $[0,1]$ can be uniformly approximated by such a function and any function in $\mathcal L^p([0,1])$ can be approximated by a continuous function in $\mathcal L^p$.

That being said, it sounds like the approach that you are using is a bit different and I think it can still work. The family that you should prove dense is the set $\mathcal P_\mathbb Q$ of polynomials with rational coefficients. Indeed, for any compact set $K \subset R$, $\mathcal P_\mathbb Q$ forms unital subalgebra of $C(K)$ which separates points and so by the Weierstrass approximation theorem $\mathcal P_\mathbb Q$ is dense in $C(K)$ in the uniform norm. Also, the $\mathcal P_{\mathbb Q}$ is countable the set of polynomials over an infinite set has the same cardinality as the set itself (that is, $\mathcal P_\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q$ have the same cardinality.

Take $f \in \mathcal L^p([0,1]).$ By integrability of $\lvert f \rvert^p$, we know that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is $\delta > 0$ such that $$\lambda(E) < \delta \,\,\, \implies \,\,\, \int_E \lvert f \rvert^p d\lambda < \epsilon.$$

Take $\epsilon > 0$ and let $\delta > 0$ be as above. Notice, we can shrink $\delta$ later if necessary. By Lusin's theorem, we can find an open set $E = E(\delta) \subset [0,1]$ with $\lambda(E) < \delta$ and $f \,\big|_{[0,1]\setminus E}$ continuous. Since $[0,1] \setminus E$ is compact, we can find a polynomial $\tilde f$ with rational coefficients such that $$\sup_{x \in [0,1] \setminus E} \lvert f(x) - \tilde f(x) \rvert < \delta.$$ Then we see \begin{align*} \int_{[0,1]} \lvert f-\tilde f \rvert^p d\lambda &= \int_{[0,1] \setminus E} \lvert f - \tilde f \rvert ^p d\lambda + \int_{E} \lvert f - \tilde f \rvert d\lambda \\
&\le \int_{[0,1] \setminus E} \delta^p d\lambda + \int_{E} \lvert f - \tilde f \rvert d\lambda \\
&\le \delta^p + \int_{E} \lvert f - \tilde f \rvert d\lambda \end{align*}

We use some rather crude bounds for the other term. We see \begin{align*}\lvert f - \tilde f \rvert^p \le(\lvert f \rvert + \lvert \tilde f \rvert)^p \le 2^p \max\{\lvert f \rvert, \lvert \tilde f \rvert\}^p &= 2^{p} \max\{ \lvert f \rvert^p, \lvert \tilde f \rvert^p\} \\
&\le 2^p(\lvert f \rvert^p + \lvert \tilde f \rvert^p)
\end{align*} Then \begin{align*}\int_E \lvert f - \tilde f \rvert^p d\lambda &\le 2^p \int_E \lvert f \rvert^p d\lambda + 2^p \int_E \lvert \tilde f \rvert^p d\lambda \\ \le 2^p\epsilon + M \delta \end{align*} where $M = \max_{x\in [0,1]} \lvert \tilde f(x) \rvert < \infty$. This all gives $$\int_{[0,1]} \lvert f - \tilde f \rvert d\lambda < \delta^p+ 2^p \epsilon + 2^p M \delta$$ and the right hand side can be made arbitrarily small showing that $P_\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathcal L^p([0,1])$.